# Rename a column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with column named region. Sample values are
Eg. `region_1, region_2, region_3` etc.

I need to replace these values to
Eg. `1,2,3`, etc.

Any specific function to deal with this easy transformation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need split with select second value and if necessary convert to integers:

```
df.region = df.region.str.split('_').str[1].astype(int)
```

Or use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex for extract integers:

```
df.region = df.region.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'region':['region_1','region_2','region_3']})
df.region = df.region.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
print (df)
   region
0       1
1       2
2       3
```